# Script type template include script tag

Tags: javascript, templates

Script type text/template include the script tag ignore closed script tag.
In the following is my sample code
Html

```
<div id="container">
</div>

<script id="template" type="text/template">
    <script>
        (function () {
            alert('@Replacement')
        }());
    </script>
</script>
```

Js

```
var template = $("#template").html();
template = template.replace("Replacement", "Hi");
$('#container').text(template);
```

I expect that after running javascript following display on the page

```
<script>
    (function () {
        alert('@Replacement')
    }());
</script>
```

But  ignored in result as the follwing:

```
<script>
    (function () {
        alert('@Replacement')
    }());
```

Comment: Why do you have a script tag inside a script tag?

Comment: Also, templateHtml is not defined

Comment: @MonicaAcha — `templateHtml` is defined on line two of the JS code example.

Comment: @MonicaAcha — Because the script element is being used as a hack to provide a template, and the template includes a script element.

Comment: @Monica Acha, this is code that I want some of my Client site copay that, this is a sample code

Comment: @Monica Acha, thanks, I edit code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content of a script tag is treated as plain text.

So the `<script>` start tag inside is treated as text, and the *first* `</script>` end tag is treated as the end of the script element.

The second `</script>` end tag is then discarded because there is no matching, open script element.

---

Use a `<script>` element as a place to hold a template is a dirty hack. You've just found a point where it breaks.

Consider using a [`<template>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) instead. Mind out for browser support.

Comment: template tag browser support is a constraint

Comment: @MohammadAkbari — So is "Hacking a script element won't work"