# How to include javascript in template block

Tags: javascript, ej2-syncfusion

I'm using the ej2 javascript Grid by Syncfusion. The following is a simplification of the actual code.
In the grid definition I have a column having a template, like this :

`{ field: "Quantity", headerText: "Quantity", template: "#colQuantity" },`

```
<script id="colQuantity" type="text/x-template">
    ${quantity}
</script>
```

What I want to achieve here is to have a format "N4" in the quantity field, so the value is prettier. Is there a way to add a `.toFixed(4)` or a `format("N4")` somewhere in the template, or a way to rewrite this template so the format is applied?

Comment: [Possible dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54864624/script-type-template-include-script-tag)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that a template can call a javascript function and pass in data.
The following code made it work.

```
<script>
    function formatNumber(args) {
        return args.quantity.toFixed(4);
    }
</script>

<script id="colQuantity" type="text/x-template">
    ${formatNumber(data)}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the columns definition for the grid, in the definition for that column, use something like:

```
...
, columns: [ ...
         { field: 'Quantity', headerText: 'Quantity', width: 120, clipMode: 'EllipsisWithTooltip', type: 'string', format: 'N4', textAlign: 'Right' },...
        ], ...
```

Comment: I remember why I could not use this solution. It's because the field value is nested in a subclass and I didn't had the choice of using a template function. But you're right, it should work this way using a simple model.